# while loop not generating output

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

what is the problem with the following code:

```
a = '2011.txt'
years = ['2011', '2011', '2011', '2012', '2013']
i = 0
while i < len(years):
    if a.endswith(years[i] + '.txt'):
        print(years[i] + '.txt')
        i += 1
```

expected output:

```
2011.txt
2011.txt
2011.txt
```

Comment: What is your actual output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `if` condition is false you are not incrementing `i`

dedent the last line like this.

```
a = '2011.txt'
years = ['2011', '2011', '2011', '2012', '2013']
i = 0
while i < len(years):
    if a.endswith(years[i] + '.txt'):
        print(years[i] + '.txt')
    i += 1
```

It's better to just use a `for` loop though (say goodbye to "off-by-one" bugs)

```
a = '2011.txt'
years = ['2011', '2011', '2011', '2012', '2013']
for item in years:
    if a.endswith(item + '.txt'):
        print(item + '.txt')
```

If you also need a loop counter, use `enumerate`

```
a = '2011.txt'
years = ['2011', '2011', '2011', '2012', '2013']
for i, item in enumerate(years):
    if a.endswith(item + '.txt'):
        print(item + '.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = '2011.txt'
years = ['2011', '2011', '2011', '2012', '2013']
i = 0
for i in years:
    if a.endswith(i + '.txt'):
        print(i + '.txt')
```

You are not incrementing `i` when condition is false

use `for` or something like above

```
O/p 

2011.txt
2011.txt
2011.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = '2011.txt'
years = ['2011', '2011', '2011', '2012', '2013']
i = 0
while i < len(years):
    if a.endswith(years[i] + '.txt'):
        print(years[i] + '.txt')
    i += 1
```